# global variable cannot be found - window in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this Node.js code (Node.js version 8.5.0):

```
try {
    window.__karma__.complete();
}
finally { 

}
```

and I am getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

this seems pretty bizarre, considering this is in a try/catch block.

Anybody know how/why this could happen? I am on Ubuntu, I swear this does not happen on my MacOS machine. I am writing `universal/isomorphic` code - if window is defined, I should be in the browser.

Comment: The error isn't being caught so the runtime will still log it usually even though the flow will continue to the `finally` block

Comment: yeah you're probably right, pretty weird though, because I swear it wasn't happening on my MacOS machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said,
this is in a `try/catch` block, but you missed the exception catching part.

```
try {
  window.__karma__.complete();
} finally {}
// -> ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

This works:

```
try {
  window.__karma__.complete();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)  // -> [ReferenceError: window is not defined]
} finally {}
```

Comment: I think because the `catch` block was missing, Node.js was simply logging the error without actually throwing the error.